# How to get table structure from .frm files in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-recovery

I have .frm files how I can get just structure of the table I have tried a lot of methods but couldn't succeeded .

Answer (score 4):

You can recover table structure from FRM files on a [web interface](http://recovery.twindb.com/) to [mysqlfrm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqlfrm.html) and some other recovery techniques.
[image: Upload form]
[image: Recovered sakila structure]

Answer (score 2):

Check out the MySQL Utility [mysqlfrm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqlfrm.html).  The mysqlfrm utility is designed as a recovery tool that reads .frm files and produces facsimile CREATE statements from the table definition data found in the file.

[MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/index.html) is both a set of command-line utilities as well as a Python library for making the common tasks easy to accomplish.  Downloads are available for both GPL and commercial editions.

Comment: mysqlfrm <datadir>/table1.frm --port 3333 --basedir <MySQL Installations's basedir>